# I am new to this google script. How to send automated emails (consisting a hyperlink) to multiple addresses in google sheets using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the below code I am able to send automated emails and it's partly successful. I am not sure how to get the hyperlink in the email.

//For this code I am able to send it to all the emails but without hyperlink

```
function testnotif() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").activate();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  
  var templatetext = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  
  for (var i=2;i<=lr;i++){
    
    var currentemail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var currenttitle = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var currentname = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var sheetID = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    
    var messagebody = templatetext.replace("{name}",currentname).replace("{title}",currenttitle).replace("{sheet}",sheetID);
    var subjectline = "Reminder: " + currenttitle ;
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentemail,subjectline,messagebody);
    
  }
  
}
```

//

//In this code I am able to send hyperlink but unable to send it to multiple email addresses

```
function testnotif(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1HVktteGM2wRXNuneZ1VVqtVg3G4WvkeFIcrLq4v-8M4');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(lr, 1).getValue();
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:data,
    subject: "Monthly test",
    htmlBody: "Hi Team,<br><br>"+"This is a gentle reminder to start your test and complete it by 25th of this month. You can find your test Dashboard in this " +"<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dyjQO51zqBo6DRXB48r7azy_ktFa1LwpIJ55DflDHOA/edit#gid=0\">sheet.</a>"+"<br><br>Let me know if you have any questions. "+"<br><br>Thank you."
});
}
```

//

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `cc` or `bcc`, whether you want the additional recipients to be visible or not:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
        to:data,
        cc: `email@address.com, email2@address.com`,
        // or hide recipients:
        // bcc: `email@address.com, email2@address.com`,
        subject: "Monthly test",
        htmlBody: "Hi Team,<br><br>"+"This is a gentle reminder to start your test and complete it by 25th of this month. You can find your test Dashboard in this " +"<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dyjQO51zqBo6DRXB48r7azy_ktFa1LwpIJ55DflDHOA/edit#gid=0\">sheet.</a>"+"<br><br>Let me know if you have any questions. "+"<br><br>Thank you."
    });
```

Edit:

If you have a column of email address you're aiming to put into the `cc` or `bcc` field, you will need to convert them into a comma-separated `string`:

```
const recipients = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                 .getSheetByName(`Emails`)
                                 .getRange(`A2:A`) // Adjust as needed.
                                 .getValues()
                                 .filter(Boolean) // Remove empty rows.
                                 // If the primary recipient is in the last row:
                                 //.slice(0, -1)
                                 .flat()
                                 .join(`, `) // Convert to comma-separated string.

// recipients = "email@address.com, email2@address.com, ..."

MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: data,
        cc: recipients,
        // or hide recipients:
        // bcc: `email@address.com, email2@address.com`,
        subject: "Monthly test",
        htmlBody: "Hi Team,<br><br>"+"This is a gentle reminder to start your test and complete it by 25th of this month. You can find your test Dashboard in this " +"<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dyjQO51zqBo6DRXB48r7azy_ktFa1LwpIJ55DflDHOA/edit#gid=0\">sheet.</a>"+"<br><br>Let me know if you have any questions. "+"<br><br>Thank you."
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the solution. However, there are several email addresses to which I need to send an email. Is there any way that I could read it from the google sheet and then run it through the script?

Comment: I've updated my response to include gathering all recipient addresses. Let me know if this is what you're asking for

Comment: Hi Newaza, It is correct what you have suggested and it has worked. Thank you very much.